# PHP Crypt Function with User input

Tags: php, html, forms, input, crypt

So I was looking at the [PHP Crypt Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php)

and I was wondering if you could make this into a user input form type deal.

Like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmvkV.png) so when they submit the whatever they entered it will output the crpyt() function after they submit it and crpyt whatever they entered (eg. Like a password or something.)

Sorry if this was answered before, I couldn't seem to find it! Any help on this would be great! Thanks.

Comment: *Mind has been twisted into too many shapes here*. - ***Huh?!***

Comment: Just do a form and when its post, write in document the hashed string

Comment: @Carlos2W What do you mean? Can you provide me with an example?

Comment: What you are asking for is VERY basic. I would recommend that you go through a beginning tutorial into the PHP language. W3 has some great ones http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Comment: what makes you think it couldn't be? PHP's raison d'etre is to take text input from a user, mangle it in one or more ways, and output stuff.

Comment: @MarcB Getting out your *"bon français"* I see.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: tomorrow I may stick out a pinky finger will sipping tea

Comment: @MarcB *LMHO!* - Just like John Bonham I take it ;-) Yeah, he used to do that. God rest his Rock 'n Roll ♫ soul. [*Tea for one anyone?*.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rgfXPlpneyE)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use it in the browser, it will be simplier to use javascript equivalent library. Take a look at [PHP function crypt in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16996030/php-function-crypt-in-javascript), the example is given.

Comment: that should be a possible duplicate then